# Remove Duplicates from LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, left-join, outer-join

My question is quite similar to [Restricting a LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757957/restricting-a-left-join), with a variation.

Assuming I have a table SHOP and another table LOCATION. Location is a sort of child table of table SHOP, that has two columns of interest, one is a Division Key  (calling it just KEY) and a "SHOP" number. This matches to the Number "NO" in table SHOP.

I tried this left outer join:

```
SELECT S.NO, L.KEY
FROM SHOP S
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATN L ON S.NO = L.SHOP
```

but I'm getting a lot of duplicates since there are many locations that belong to a single shop. I want to eliminate them and just get a list of "shop, key" entries without duplicates.

The data is correct but duplicates appear as follows:

```
SHOP     KEY
 1       XXX
 1       XXX
 2       YYY
 3       ZZZ
 3       ZZZ  etc.
```

I would like the data to appear like this instead:

```
SHOP     KEY
 1       XXX
 2       YYY
 3       ZZZ  etc.
```

SHOP table:

```
 NO
 1       
 2       
 3
```

LOCATION table:

```
 LOCATION   SHOP  KEY
   L-1       1    XXX   
   L-2       1    XXX   
   L-3       2    YYY   
   L-4       3    YYY   
   L-5       3    YYY
```

(ORACLE 10g Database)

Comment: You shouldn't be getting any duplicates, though, as you stated, you may get more than one key for a shop if you have more than one location record for the shop. Please explain or give an example of what you mean by "duplicate".

Comment: @Marcus I thought the same at first but I'm assuming that multiple locations can have the same division key.

Comment: @Marcus & Martin: ah i don't think i made this clear. Yes Multiple locations can and do have a same division key. 

(Strictly speaking divnkey is the parent of shop. So hierarchy goes like this Divnkey > Shop > location). I'm trying to populate Shop's table with the appropriate division key data. May sound weird, but it's a one time process and i was trying to generate update scripts for  table SHOP from the table LOCATION's data - through a select 'update shop set divnkey = ....' command. Didn't want to complicate the question so put a simple select.

Comment: Sorry only just saw your response. Will update my answer again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY 'S.No' & 'L.KEY'

```
SELECT S.NO, L.KEY 
FROM SHOP S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATN L 
ON S.NO = L.SHOP
GROUP BY S.NO, L.KEY
```

Comment: +1 for using `GROUP BY` which is equivalent to `DISTINCT` on Oracle http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32961403234212 but can sometimes be faster on other engines e.g. Postgres (using hashes instead of sorting.)

Comment: Ok you just made me feel reaally stupid. This works perfectly. Thanks. 

But any additional comments on why the group by is required at all when  the left outer is supposed to take care of this. As in i'm trying to understand how the left outer really works.

Comment: @Kaushik: A LEFT OUTER JOIN is not equivalent to nor does it imply a GROUP BY or DISTINCT. The LEFT JOIN takes all rows from the left (first) table, and joins in all rows from the right (second) table where the join condition is satisfied. In an left *outer* join, if there is no data found in the right table which matches data from the left table the left-table data is still returned with NULLs put in for all right-table data. No grouping is expressed or implied. Personally I'd have used DISTINCT as I think it more clearly specifies intent, but YMMV.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for clarifying. I misunderstood what was meant by a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I presumed it to be different from a normal LEFT JOIN. Now i understand them to be the same?

For the interwebs: A helpful link by Jeff A on understanding the whole join concept: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @Kaushik - yes, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are equivalent because the OUTER keyword is optional.  If you specify FULL, LEFT, or RIGHT as the join type you can skip specifying OUTER, but I usually put it in because I think it helps make the code clearer.  (I know - I didn't put OUTER into my earlier comment - but, um, I was trying to fit everything into the 600 character limit!  Yeah, that's the ticket..! :-)

Comment: I really hope this doesn't start a fashion for using group by instead of distinct. Isn't the postgres issue pre-8.1?

Comment: You cannot imagine how you saved my day , thank you, +++ to you

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** Following the update in your scenario

I think you should be able to do this with a simple sub query (though I haven't tested this against an Oracle database). Something like the following

```
UPDATE shop s
SET divnkey = (SELECT DISTINCT L.KEY FROM LOCATN L WHERE S.NO = L.SHOP)
```

The above will raise an error in the event of a shop being associated with locations that are in multiple divisions.

If you just want to ignore this possibility and select an arbitrary one in that event you could use

```
UPDATE shop s
SET divnkey = (SELECT MAX(L.KEY) FROM LOCATN L WHERE S.NO = L.SHOP)
```

Comment: Nice :) This is why it's important to get more than one angle. Thanks Martin, your solution most definitely satisfies my underlying requirement (But the other answer specifically takes care of removing the duplicates, so going to have to mark that one). Cheers

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too but I couldn't use GROUP BY to fix it because I was also returning TEXT type fields. (Same goes for using DISTINCT).

This code gave me duplicates:

```
select mx.*, case isnull(ty.ty_id,0) when 0 then 'N' else 'Y' end as inuse 
from master_x mx 
left outer join thing_y ty on mx.rpt_id = ty.rpt_id
```

I fixed it by rewriting it thusly:

```
select mx.*, 
case when exists (select 1 from thing_y ty where mx.rpt_id = ty.rpt_id) then 'Y' else 'N' end as inuse
from master_x mx
```

As you can see I didn't care about the data within the 2nd table (`thing_y`), just whether there was greater than zero matches on the `rpt_id` within it. (FYI: `rpt_id` was also not the primary key on the 1st table, `master_x`).