# SQL - remove duplicates from left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm creating a joined view of two tables, but am getting unwanted duplicates from table2.
For example: table1 has 9000 records and I need the resulting view to contain exactly the same; table2 may have multiple records with the same FKID but I only want to return one record (random chosen is ok with my customer).  I have the following code that works correctly, but performance is slower than desired (over 14 seconds).

```
SELECT     
    OBJECTID
    , PKID
    ,(SELECT TOP (1) SUBDIVISIO
        FROM dbo.table2 AS t2
        WHERE (t1.PKID = t2.FKID)) AS ProjectName
    ,(SELECT TOP (1) ASBUILT1
        FROM dbo.table2 AS t2
        WHERE (t1.PKID = t2.FKID)) AS Asbuilt
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
```

Is there a way to do something similar with joins to speed up performance?
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.
I got close with the following code (~.5 seconds), but 'Distinct' only filters out records when all columns are duplicate (rather than just the FKID).

```
SELECT
    t1.OBJECTID
    ,t1.PKID
    ,t2.ProjectName
    ,t2.Asbuilt
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
        DISTINCT FKID
        ,ProjectName
        ,Asbuilt
        FROM dbo.table2) t2
    ON t1.PKID = t2.FKID
```

table examples

```
table1          table2

OID, PKID       FKID, ProjectName, Asbuilt
1, id1          id1, P1, AB1
2, id2          id1, P5, AB5
3, id4          id2, P10, AB2
5, id5          id5, P4, AB4
```

In the above example returned records should be id5/P4/AB4, id2/P10/AB2, and (id1/P1/AB1 OR id1/P5/AB5)

My search came up with similar questions, but none that resolved my problem.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757957/restricting-a-left-join), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns)
Thanks in advance for your help.  This is my first post so let me know if I've broken any rules.

Comment: Wouldn't adding DISTINCT to the first SELECT fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will give the results you requested and should have the best performance.

```
SELECT     
    OBJECTID
    , PKID
    , t2.SUBDIVISIO,
    , t2.ASBUILT1

FROM        dbo.table1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    dbo.table2 AS t2
    WHERE   t1.PKID = t2.FKID
    ) AS t2
```

Comment: this works also!  I'll have to look further into the OUTER APPLY.

Comment: @RickMomsen Just out of curiosity, how fast is it now?

Comment: This is my solution since it consistently returns an entire record.

Comment: 6891ms compared with 7581ms (my sub select query).  I should note that I have to run this against a view rather than the source table.  Your query is faster than the others (mentioned so far) when ran against either the view or the source table; except Gordon's option2 had little performance difference between table or view

Answer (score 3):

Your original query is producing arbitrary values for the two columns (the use of `top` with no `order by`).  You can get the same effect with this:

```
SELECT t1.OBJECTID, t1.PKID, t2.ProjectName, t2.Asbuilt
FROM dbo.table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT FKID, min(ProjectName) as ProjectName, MIN(asBuilt) as AsBuilt
      FROM dbo.table2
      group by fkid
     ) t2
    ON t1.PKID = t2.FKID
```

This version replaces the `distinct` with a `group by`.

To get a truly random row in SQL Server (which your syntax suggests you are using), try this:

```
SELECT t1.OBJECTID, t1.PKID, t2.ProjectName, t2.Asbuilt
FROM dbo.table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT FKID, ProjectName, AsBuilt,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by fkid order by newid()) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.table2
     ) t2
    ON t1.PKID = t2.FKID and t2.seqnum = 1
```

This assumes version 2005 or greater.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  I tried option1 but the group by kept failing b/c the other fields were not aggregated.  I also tried option2 but couldn't get it to work.  I'm going to go with option1 because of the consistent output.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to uncheck your answer.  the "MIN" in the sub select actually mixes values between the records and I prefer to have a complete record returned.  This way the client won't get confused on which record needs to be updated.  I appreciate the education!

Comment: I thought it would be worthy to note that your option2 is far faster than other queries when ran against a view. (364ms vs 7581ms and 6891ms)

Comment: @RickMomsen . . . Your original query also mixed results, which is why I wrote it that way (and I tried to explain that in the first sentence).  I'm a bit surprised that the second version runs faster, but the window functions are highly optimized.

Comment: You're right Gordon.  The performance concern stopped me before I investigated the results and knew that would be an issue.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want described result, you need to use `INNER JOIN` and following query will satisfy your need:

```
SELECT
  t1.OID,
  t1.PKID,
  MAX(t2.ProjectName) AS ProjectName,
  MAX(t2.Asbuilt) AS Asbuilt
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.PKID = t2.FKID
GROUP BY
  t1.OID,
  t1.PKID
```

If you want to see all rows from left table (**table1**) whether it has pair in right table or not, then use `LEFT JOIN` and same query will gave you desired result.

**EDITED**

This construction has good performance, and you dont need to use subqueries.

Comment: This works too, but has the same MIN/MAX issues as Gordon's Option1 above.

Comment: I agree, but I am using simple JOIN instead derived table.